# Is losing money on stocks actually simpler than gaining money?

Tags: stocks, trading, capital-loss

Suppose that I want to invest X amount of cash in stocks, with the goal of doubling the value of my portfolio inside a given time period.
This is notoriously hard, in particular there is no full-proof (100% certain) way of doing it. One could perhaps do some statistics to evaluate the probability of this event actually happening, averaging over all the possible stock investment in the past.

Suppose now that I'm interested in the reverse process, that is investing in stock to lose half of my portfolio value inside a given time period.

Is losing value actually simpler than gaining money or is the process symmetric?

I'm only allowed to use publicly available informations on the stock market.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2270)

Comment: Though I answered the question as asked, I'll just also point out that losing 50% is not symmetrical with gaining 100%; that would be a gain of 100% vs losing everything, like if you bet me $1 on the flip of a coin.

Comment: @glibdud Note that the fundemental problem with the author's intended point, is that if you pick risky enough stocks, and they go bankrupt, you can't ever pull back from a complete portfolio loss. So losing all of your money in the stock market is indeed easier than gaining money.  It also sidesteps some critical definitions of 'risk' and 'average', ie: mean vs median vs mode, defining things in a way that seems to make sense but falls under scrutiny.

Comment: Did you mean "foolproof"?

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon: But a lot of that depends on just how one goes about defining the concept of "easy".  To me, investing in individual stocks is much more difficult than just putting money in an index fund, and it's really hard to lose money that way over the long term.  And to keep churning your account, the way you would have to in order to lose lots of money quickly, is harder still.

Comment: @jamesqf If you pick a risky enough stock [start with a list of companies that are in the process of declaring bankruptcy], believe me, you won't need a lot of churn before everything is gone.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the relevance of this question to any real world situation other than a plot point in "Brewster's Millions" There are much easier ways to lose money than the stock market.

Comment: Buy stock. Sell it for less than it is worth. What is your question really?

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon: Sure, but hunting out those risky stocks & buying shares still takes a certain amount of work, which is likely to be more than it would take to invest the money in a probably profitable index fund.

Comment: @jamesqf Remember that the question is whether it is 'easier to double your money or lose half of it'. Doubling your money is not easy unless you are waiting decades to do so.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon: Yes?  Putting money in mutual funds and waiting is not easy?  On average, money invested in an S&P 500 index fund doubled in about 9 years.  (Insert obligatory "past performance..." disclaimer here :-))  While I can't find exact figures, a bit of searching suggests the typical day trader loses half their starting capital in under two years.

Comment: @jamesqf I completely agree, and noted as such in my answer; I feel however that OP may not have been expecting to wait 10 years to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is easier to lose money in the stock market, if you are trying to. This has less to do with 'the odds being stacked against you', or something like that, it just has more to do with probability and how 'risk' is defined in finance.

**Let's assume first of all that every stock has an even chance of moving up vs moving down, on average** [in reality, the stock market over time goes up, as long as the general economy moves forward, and a rule of thumb for western markets is about 7% annually *on average*, per year, over a large amount of time, which includes some years of big losses and some years of big gains]. **In finance, 'risk' is defined as the *variance in possible returns***, and actually isn't the same as 'overall how bad of an investment it is'; 2 investments can have the same return on average, but have different risk levels. **Let's take a look at how financial risk impacts 3 companies which, on average, have the same expected 'flat' return:**

1. One company might have a 50% chance of moving up 1%, and 50% chance of moving down 1%. That is not very risky - because no matter what happens, the stock price will be very close to where it started.
2. Another company might have a 50% chance of moving down 30%, and a 50% chance of moving up 30%. This is quite risky, even though, on average, it is 'expected to have a net return of 0%', because the probability of an increase exactly matches the probability of a decrease. The math on this is: Expected return = 50% * 1.3 + 50% * 0.7 = 100% [100% meaning you return exactly the same as you put in, on average, even though sometimes you go up and sometimes you go down]. So this is quite a bit riskier than the 1% up / down company example above.
3. A final company might have a 10% chance of going up 5x, a 50% chance of staying the same, and a 40% chance of going completely bust. The expected return would be 10% * 500% + 50% * 100% + 40% * 0 = 100%. So the average return would be the same, but the risk would be massive. Every year, you have a 40% chance of losing everything, a 50% chance of having no gains or losses, and a 10% chance of going up 5x. The only way to make money at this would be if you 'strike it rich', for example a junior biotech company finding a major medical breakthrough, which would only happen 1 year out of 10.

**If the above hypothetical holds true, you could very easily lose all your money** (you would do so 4 years out of every 10, if you invested in example #3). Yet, you would only double your money [and then some] 1 year out of every ten. Far harder to do so, *because you have chosen an investment where the most likely outcome is failure, even though success looks really really good*.

Now, in reality, the riskier the company, the higher you should expect to earn from it. If you have to risk losing everything, you should earn more on average than a riskless investment, right? That does impact things in real life, but there are still 'moonshot' investments that have a very high chance of failure, even though the small chance of success means that some people happily take that risk to earn more money on average.

*As a side note to answering the question directly, I'll add that the simplest way to mitigate risk in the stock market is to broadly invest in a diversified portfolio, meaning for example to simply buy an index fund that covers the return of the whole stock market, with minimal management fees. This would, on average, give you the return of the whole market, which again as a rule of thumb might average out to 7% over, say, a 20 year period*.

In that sense, as long as the economy doesn't completely collapse, and you leave your investments in for long enough, it is actually quite simple [though not guaranteed] to earn money in the stock market. And by the way, with compounding, 7% / year works out to just about doubling your money every 10 years, and when you start investing young, this is the best tool you have to saving for retirement - simply letting compounding on average returns do its thing.

Comment: This is a good answer, the possibility of a company going bankrupt is breaking the symmetry, making it easier to lose money. But the overall growing trend of the market is breaking it too, in the other direction. It is not clear what the end result is.

Comment: Another minor point, you are implicitly making the assumption that I'm able to decide which companies will be of category 1,2,3 in the future, and to pick 3, but this may not be the case.

Comment: @Rexcirus Invest 100% of your money in any of these companies already slated for bankruptcy declaration, and you'll lose your money in no time flat. Just keep rolling the dice - even if the market goes up 7% on average every year, a single blammo hit that wipes your investment gives you the losses you dream of. https://www.investors.com/etfs-and-funds/sectors/bankrupt-companies-prove-you-can-lose-90-percent-money-stocks/

Answer (score 1):

One *related* issue.

Stocks (indeed, all markets) move downwards *faster* than they move upwards.

Maybe this is relevant to what you're wondering about.

Comment: Volatility (fear) increases in down markets which is something that traders love.  The wins are faster and easier then when the market is ambling upward steadily.

Comment: Indeed!  :)    Was bringing the info to the attention of our dear OP...

Answer (score 0):

Is it easier?  Sure.  Is it absolutely, positively 100% guaranteed?  No.

For any security, there is a spread between the bid and the ask price.  So if you buy and sell a stock and the price hasn't moved, you end up with slightly less money than you had when you started.  If you look for stocks with relatively high spreads because they are relatively illiquid and rapidly bought and sold shares in order to not impact the price, you'd expect to lose money with each cycle.  Now, you might get unlucky and the price might increase by more than the spread in the time between your two trades getting executed.  But the vast majority of the time you'd lose money.  Assuming the time span you have is long enough to allow you to have millions of these buy-sell cycles, the odds that you'd be able to lose half your money are very high.

But since we're talking about odds, it is, of course, possible that you'd get unlucky and end up holding a stock that shoots up in price in the fraction of a second you're holding it and you end up losing much less than expected.  Just as it's possible that you walk into a 7-11, buy a single lottery ticket, and end up winning the billion dollar jackpot.

Comment: I agree with your assessment but I think that the OP was referring to investing.  One could then argue that the long term trend of the market is up so there's an offset.  Either way, I find questions like this to be an exercise in futility, with no market relevance other than thought provoking hypotheticals.

Comment: @BobBaerker - It's certainly a hypothetical.  I see some relevance in realizing that the long-term trend of the market is upwards and that there is a short-term drag from trading.  If we exclude trading costs and assume only long-term investments then the xkcd in the comments is perfect.

Comment: No comprendo.  xkcd?  A webcomic?

Comment: @BobBaerker xkcd is a *classic* nerd webcomic.

Comment: I get that but how does a webcomic (that I am not familiar with) relate to the question, answer or comments?  Sarcasm?  Irony? Humor?  Still no comprendo and probably a waste of time at this point.

Comment: @BobBaerker - Did you see the link glibdud posted in the comments to this question?  The particular comic would actually be a decent answer if you just posted the text from each pane.

Comment: @JustinCave See my comment to the linked XKCD in the question above; it isn't true, because of the asymmetry of coming back from a total loss, which you could pretty easily manifest by just investing all your money in the least liquid, least capitalized company on a junior stock exchange, ie: buying penny stocks every day until one of them just goes completely bankrupt.

Comment: @BobBaerker - if you're not familiar with "xkcd" it's something of a "cult" comic online.  it often deals with technical issues or terminology.  For this reason indeed, very often people link to a "relevant" xkcd comic when discussing some issue.  so very often you will see an "xkcd comic reference" on, say, the physics or math site etc etc.  https://xkcd.com/643/

Comment: (simply google "physics.stackexchange.com xkcd" or similar, @BobBaerker , to get the idea)

Comment: furthermore @BobBaerker the most common way to do it is, say there is a QA about, I dunno, cats, and there is a funny xkcd comic about cats.  the "accepted" thing to write is "Obligatory xkcd" .. exactly like this for example [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/231/)  (click on it!)  Notice this is precisely what someone did in the very first comment under the question.

Comment: { furthermore, naturally there are 1000s of articles discussing what I just explained in the previous comment, eg, https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8085/what-is-the-genesis-of-obligatory-xkcd  .. @BobBaerker }

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make asks and bids at the market price, you can ask or bid whatever you want. The problem is that if you make a bid for half the market price (which would make you lots of money), nobody will agree to sell at that price, but if you make a bid for twice the market price (which will lose you tons of money), people will sell their shares to you in a heartbeat.

So if you act completely unreasonable, it is very easy to lose any amount of money.